# Automatically close the bitcoin-qt when enable SSL for RPC

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, security, json-rpc

I Just try to enable SSL for bitcoin-qt RPC call. I follow the [SSL on RPC](https://bitcoinsecurityproject.org/BTCProtocol/JSONRPC/)
link to archive my target. But I am getting the following error and close the bitcoin-qt automatically.

[image]

[image]

I am using the bitcoin-qt 0.16.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for SSL protected RPC was removed in Bitcoin Core version 0.12.0 (released in february 2016).

See https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.12.0#rpc-low-level-api-changes for the release notes on this, and also a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I don't understand why Bitcoin core developer is remove the SSL supported RPC on new versions...?? Actually it is decrease the security..??

Comment: Generally the RPC interface is intended for locally running services that you trust. It isn't designed to be exposed over the internet. If you have a need for that, it's probably better to develop a wrapper with protections in yourself (for example, not exposing `dumpprivkey` or `importmulti` or even `stop).

Comment: But actually I need to run it remotely. Any way are available to enable SSL for RPC call for bitcoind...???

Comment: Using of Bitcoind version 0.11 is a solution for my problem ..???

Comment: @salman farris The release notes I linked to explain how it can be done using stunnel or apache. Please, do not use 0.11. It is no longer maintained and has several critical issues.

Comment: Can you  please share the link for applying ssl using stunnel or apache for rpc of bitcoind...??

Comment: The link is in my answer.

Comment: Please answer my another question as possible. The link is https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/85816/create-a-multi-user-web-wallet-using-bitcoind-rpc-call